# How to add another value to an existing array (by concatenating)

Tags: arrays, swift, concatenation

I'm trying to figure out how to get arrayOfInts to return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] using append to add 6 and concatenating to add 7.

The error I get from the second bit is "Invalid redeclaration of 'arrayOfInts'. What am I doing wrong?

```
var arrayOfInts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

arrayOfInts.append(6) // using append
arrayOfInts // returns [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var arrayOfInts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] + [7] // concatenating
arrayOfInts // not returning anything
```

Comment: You cannot have two things called `arrayOfInts` in the same scope. You probably meant to say `arrayOfInts = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] + [7]` or `arrayOfInts = arrayOfInts + [7]` (but you should prefer to use `append(_:)` in this case as it doesn't necessarily have to copy the array)

Comment: Removed var and that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a short you are declaring the same variable two time in same scope that is arrayOfInts twice.